# pick 3rd number in String

Tags: java, regex

Given this String: "a001212a a1212a a00333a a00334a abvbv";

I'm trying to pick the third number just by changing the regex. But I can't figure it out. I am only allowed to change the regex. My code below works if i change the argument to matcher.group(2) but not for group(1).

Help?

```
String nthNumber(String string) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(
                "(\\D+0*(\\d+)\\D+){3,}.*"
        );

        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(string);
        matcher.matches();
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Comment: Given the input `a001212a a1212a a00333a a00334a abvbv` what is the expected output? `1`, `00333`, `333` or `a00333a`?

Comment: group(1) is matching a00333a?
If you'd like to match 333 with group(1), consider repacing the first `(` with `(?:` to make it a non capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the first group a non-capturing group like below. Then, group(1) should work.

```
String nthNumber(String string) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(
                "(?:\\D+0*(\\d+)\\D+){3,}.*"
        );

        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(string);
        matcher.matches();
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this what I was looking for.